# Angular 7 Webview to Android APK

Tags: android, ios, angular, ionic2, android-7.0-nougat

I have developed an application using Angular 7 with Responsive Web Design(RWD). I have converted this application into an Android APK that runs the app inside a webview. However, I have found Some of features of Native app ( like Opening Camera,Open file browser) in android App not working.

What extra effort would be needed to convert an RWD to webview Android App?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript nor code running inside a webview by their nature, do not have access to a device's hardware. You will need to access the OS's native code to be able to use them.

The easiest approach I would recommend is using a hybrid app platform such as [cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/).